# Web Game - Saving JavaScript Variables to MySQL

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, css

I'm currently working on a Web Game and I want to store the players points and level into a MySQL database. The points are constantly going up so having it autosave using POST and GET will cause the page to refresh and points will be lost ( I think ? )

Comment: Use [___`AJAX`___](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX/Getting_Started)

Comment: To further Rayon: have a php page which has all the information on it for storing data into the database (wrapped in some isset if statements so it only works if data has been posted) and then use ajax to post your data to the page without having to refresh your current page.

Comment: Could you explain this a bit more ? I don't fully understand how that would work. Links or videos would be good.

Answer (score 1):

Still can't comment, anyways AJAX is outdated. Check out the new fetch method or web workers.

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/websockets/basics/

Or just avoid the server and use Web SQL (this will disable things like top player score, top players, basically anything that is not related to streaming multi-player gaming)

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/html5/html5_web_sql.htm

Google HTML5 and JavaScript gaming tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

Bind ajax call on event like change of text value:
For example:

```
<input type="text" name="id" id="btn" onchange="ajaxfunction()"/
<script>
function ajaxfunction()
{
    enter ajax code here
}
</script>
```